# Can you add a repository SUBFOLDER to your gradle dependencies?

Tags: spring, git, maven, gradle

I'm working with https://github.com/ChargeTimeEU/Java-OCA-OCPP and I have an issue with continuous integration using the Java-OCA-OCPP library. There's an issue with this library's publication to Nexus (I believe) and therefore it can't be added to my projects dependencies through a repository (it can but for version 0.3).

My question is if there's a possibility of injecting only a "folder" from the repository rather then its release, or am I stuck with building the version I need and using a jar file? Thanks.

Comment: The Maven `install` phase would install a locally built artifact into the local repository which means you should be able to reference that artifact from other builds.

Comment: I'm not really sure how this would apply to my case, are you suggesting I build a local artifact out of the OCPP library and then use it in my project or am I getting something wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that would be one way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same problem with this library, it was solved by putting

```
implementation 'com.github.ChargeTimeEU.Java-OCA-OCPP:OCPP-J:master-SNAPSHOT'
implementation 'com.github.ChargeTimeEU.Java-OCA-OCPP:common:master-SNAPSHOT'
implementation 'com.github.ChargeTimeEU.Java-OCA-OCPP:v1_6:master-SNAPSHOT'
implementation 'com.github.ChargeTimeEU.Java-OCA-OCPP:v1_6-test:master-SNAPSHOT'
```

to gradle dependencies.
This implies the usage of jitpack in your repositories

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

Furthermore, before hitting the solution for this specific problem, we were discussing git submodule usage and I believe that to be the general answer to this question!